# Why I am not getting the same SHA-1?

Tags: git

I tried the following two commands:

```sh
philip@X230:~/Desktop/learn_git$ echo 'what is up, doc?' | git hash-object --stdin
7108f7ecb345ee9d0084193f147cdad4d2998293

philip@X230:~/Desktop/learn_git$ echo 'blob 16\u0000what is up, doc?' | openssl sha1
(stdin)= 5bc40a1cd865de7a0a4641d3d059b1216ed9042c
```

I am wondering why I am not getting te same SHA-1

Answer (score 7):

Two things:

1. `echo 'what is up, doc?'` outputs *17* characters, including the newline at the end. You should use `echo -n` (assuming bash) both times to remove the newline at the end, or adjust the length of your manually-constructed blob to 17.
2. Your `\u0000` escape is ineffective (test it, run `echo 'blob 16\u0000what is up, doc?'` to the console without piping into sha1). You need the `-e` option (again assuming bash) to make echo interpret any escapes.

If you do

```
echo -e 'blob 17\u0000what is up, doc?' | openssl sha1
```

the result is

```
(stdin)= 7108f7ecb345ee9d0084193f147cdad4d2998293
```

which matches `git hash-object` nicely.

Comment: But in this case why the `hash-object` command on a `.txt` file that contains the same string gives the same hash as the `echo -e 'blob 17\u0000what is up, doc?' | openssl sha1 ?` Does this means that git add a new line also?

Comment: @Giant8 no, it means your text file has one (which is normal).

Comment: And why it's normal ?

Comment: Think about `cat myfile myfile`, or `echo header;cat myfile;echo trailer`. Text files have to be terminated by newlines or else you can't really treat them like text files, you have to check. You keep your floors clean so you don't have to check for toys and broken glass every step.

Answer (score 3):

`echo` appends a newline to its output, so your contents are actually 17 bytes long, not 16.  Try to use `printf`, which is more standardized and doesn't do that:

```
$ printf '%s' 'what is up, doc?' | git hash-object --stdin
bd9dbf5aae1a3862dd1526723246b20206e5fc37
$ printf 'blob 16\0%s' 'what is up, doc?' | sha1sum
bd9dbf5aae1a3862dd1526723246b20206e5fc37  -
```

Comment: Is this command compatible with both macOS and linux?

Comment: `printf` is specified by POSIX, so it is indeed compatible with both macOS and Linux.  `sha1sum` is not shipped with macOS and you'll need to use a different tool instead.